# Multiplying positive integers - smaller ones first?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, computer-science, computational-complexity

Suppose that we want to multiply following integers.

```
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1092380294750349875094810257491
```

It is clear that

`(((((2*3)*4)*5)*6)*1092380294750349875094810257491)` method is faster then

`(((((1092380294750349875094810257491*6)*5)*4)*3)*2)` method.

My mind tell me that "Multiply small integers first, large integers later.. it's a common sense"

But I am not sure whether such logic can be applied to arbitrary list of integers.

Can you teach about this?

Comment: Using the traditional algorithms of arithmetic, if you multiply an n digit number by an n digit number, you will make $n\times m$ multiplications of 1 digit numbers that are then summed together in some way.  The resulting number will be an $n+m$ or an $n+m-1$ digit number.   This will give you a sense of the total number of multiplications by whichever order you choose to go by.